# WSDL API (Betdaq) input specification in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I’m having problems with specifying the right input parameters to the Betdaq’s sportsbetting API in Visual Basic, Visual Studio 2015. Here follows a part of the associated WSDL file available, which is loaded as a web reference:

```
<xs:complexType name="GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest">
   <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="EventClassifierIds" type="xs:long"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="WantDirectDescendentsOnly" type="xs:boolean" 
   use="optional"/>
   <xs:attribute name="WantPlayMarkets" type="xs:boolean" 
   use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is my current code to implement the API request:

```
Private Sub ReadMarkets()

Dim GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest As New 
BETDAQAPI.GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest

GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.WantDirectDescendentsOnly = True
GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.WantPlayMarkets = True

End Sub
```

I’m struggling with adding the "EventClassifierIds" specification correctly. I only intend to add one EventClassifierId = 10004, but

GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.EventClassifierIds = 100004

wont work, since input is required to be in form of “Long()”. What's the workaround here? This is clearly some syntax I’m not getting, and every kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show where `GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.EventClassifierIds = 100004` falls into the code? 100004 qualifies as a Long Integer (up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

Comment: Running:
   Private Sub ReadMarkets()

   Dim GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest As New 
   BETDAQAPI.GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest

   GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.EventClassifierIds(0) = 
   100004
   GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.WantDirectDescendentsOnly = 
   True
   GetEventSubTreeNoSelectionsRequest.WantPlayMarkets = True

   End Sub

Yields the error message: “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

Comment: Hi @Jacob this may be a long shot, but I've found this question from years ago and I'd really like to know if there's a list somewhere of all the EventClassifierIds? Your question has 100004 which I know now is Horse Racing but this is the only thing on the internet Ive found showing any source for sport codes.

Comment: @Sam Make an API request: `ListTopLevelEventsRequest` to get the top level event classifiers.